# Using Apply() in R similar to how it's used in Sql Server?

Tags: r

So I've got a data frame like below:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+  
| Policy_NO | Creation_Date | Limit | Limit_Date |  
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  1000 | 8/31/2015  |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  2000 | 9/30/2015  |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  5000 | 10/22/2015 |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |   500 | 11/17/2015 |  
| A00003    | 9/21/2015     |  3000 | 1/1/2016   |  
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+
```

And what I want is to have an 'End_Limit_Date' which should either be the date of the next limit with the same policy number -1 or exactly one year from the Creation date.

For example, the table above should be:

```
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|  Policy_NO  Creation_Date  Limit  Limit_Date   | End_Limit_Date |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| A00001     8/31/2015       1000  8/31/2015     | 9/29/2015      |
| A00001     8/31/2015       2000  9/30/2015     | 10/21/2015     |
| A00001     8/31/2015       5000  10/22/2015    | 11/16/2015     |
| A00001     8/31/2015        500  11/17/2015    | 8/31/2016      |
| A00003     9/21/2015       3000  1/1/2016      | 9/21/2016      |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Now in sql server, this can be achieved by using an outer apply like below:

```
SELECT  t.Policy_NO,
        t.Creation_Date,
        t.Limit,
        t.Limit_Date,
        End_Limit_Date = ISNULL(
                            DATEADD(DAY, -1, t2.Limit_Date), 
                            DATEADD(YEAR, 1, t.Creation_Date))
FROM    dbo.T 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 t2.Limit_Date
            FROM    dbo.T AS t2
            WHERE   t2.Policy_NO = t.Policy_NO
            AND     t2.Limit_Date > t.Limit_Date
            ORDER BY t2.Limit_Date
        ) AS t2;
```

but I was wondering if there's a way to do this in R with data frames?
I've looked into using the sqldf package (https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#FAQ)
, and I don't think it's supported.
I do know that R itself has several apply functions (https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/), and I was wondering if I can achieve the same result using this?

Input data:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Policy_NO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A00001", 
"A00003"), class = "factor"), Creation_Date = structure(c(16678, 
16678, 16678, 16678, 16699), class = "Date"), Limit = c(1000L, 
2000L, 5000L, 500L, 3000L), Limit_Date = structure(c(16678, 16708, 
16730, 16756, 16801), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Policy_NO", 
"Creation_Date", "Limit", "Limit_Date"), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059 You need a split-apply-combine function. I would use package data.table for this.

Comment: I think the fact that R and SQL both have `apply` functions is just a coincidence; in my experience of using both SQL's `CROSS APPLY` / `OUTER APPLY` and R's `*apply` family, the functionality provided by each are just fundamentally different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default backend of sqldf is SQLite and SQLite is not very good for processing dates because it has no date class -- it does have date functions but these are not standard SQL and there are other problems; however, you can get close to your SQL statement by using the H2 backend of sqldf and a self-join.  Note that `LIMIT` is a keyword and must be escaped.  Also note that the first time you use the H2 package in a session it will load rJava so the first H2 query in any session will be slow.

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2)

sql <- "SELECT 
          t.Policy_NO,
          t.Creation_Date,
          t.`Limit`,
          t.Limit_Date,
          ISNULL( DATEADD('DAY', -1, MIN(t2.Limit_Date)), 
                  DATEADD('YEAR', 1, t.Creation_Date)) End_Limit_Date
        FROM df t
        LEFT JOIN df t2 ON t2.Policy_NO = t.Policy_NO
                        AND t2.Limit_Date > t.Limit_Date
        GROUP BY t.Policy_NO, t.Creation_Date, t.`Limit`, t.Limit_Date
        ORDER BY 1, 2, 4
"

sqldf(sql)
```

giving:

```
> sqldf(sql)
  Policy_NO Creation_Date Limit Limit_Date End_Limit_Date
1    A00001    2015-08-31  1000 2015-08-31     2015-09-29
2    A00001    2015-08-31  2000 2015-09-30     2015-10-21
3    A00001    2015-08-31  5000 2015-10-22     2015-11-16
4    A00001    2015-08-31   500 2015-11-17     2016-08-31
5    A00003    2015-09-21  3000 2016-01-01     2016-09-21
```

**Note:** If you do want to use the default SQLite backend then be sure that RH2 is *not* loaded and try this.  Note that SQLite functions assume that date numbers count from an origin 2440588 days earlier than the UNIX Epoch used in R's `"Date"` class, hence the translation by this amount.  The `date` function produces the date of an SQLite date number as a character string and the `julianday` function is its inverse (except that it measures from noon so we have to use an offset of 0.5).  We use the`name__class` method of `sqldf` to cause a translation back to `"Date"` class for those variables whose name ends in `__Date` (two underscores).

```
library(sqldf)


sql <- 'SELECT 
          t.Policy_NO,
          t.Creation_Date Creation_Date__Date,
          t."Limit",
          t.Limit_Date Limit_Date__Date,
          IFNULL(MIN(t2.Limit_Date) - 1, 
                 julianday(date(t.Creation_Date + 2440588, "+1 year")) - 2440588 + 0.5
                ) End_Limit_Date__Date
        FROM    df t
        LEFT JOIN df t2 ON t2.Policy_NO = t.Policy_NO
                        AND t2.Limit_Date > t.Limit_Date
        GROUP BY t.rowid
        ORDER by t.rowid'

sqldf(sql, method = "name__class")
```

Answer (score 3):

Input data:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Policy_NO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A00001", 
"A00003"), class = "factor"), Creation_Date = structure(c(16678, 
16678, 16678, 16678, 16699), class = "Date"), Limit = c(1000L, 
2000L, 5000L, 500L, 3000L), Limit_Date = structure(c(16678, 16708, 
16730, 16756, 16801), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Policy_NO", 
"Creation_Date", "Limit", "Limit_Date"), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Using library `dplyr`, you can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(Policy_NO, Limit_Date) %>% 
  group_by(Policy_NO) %>% 
  mutate(End_Limit_Date = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(lead(Limit_Date)), 
                                         Creation_Date + 366, 
                                         lead(Limit_Date) - 1)))
```

Output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: Policy_NO [2]

  Policy_NO Creation_Date Limit Limit_Date End_Limit_Date
     (fctr)        (date) (int)     (date)         (date)
1    A00001    2015-08-31  1000 2015-08-31     2015-09-29
2    A00001    2015-08-31  2000 2015-09-30     2015-10-21
3    A00001    2015-08-31  5000 2015-10-22     2015-11-16
4    A00001    2015-08-31   500 2015-11-17     2016-08-31
5    A00003    2015-09-21  3000 2016-01-01     2016-09-21
```

Note, you need to convert the dates to proper date format as follows:

```
df$Creation_Date <- as.Date(df$Creation_Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
df$Limit_Date <- as.Date(df$Limit_Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: If you went to the trouble of recreating the example data, can you please just add the `dput` output to the question body?